# Angular subscription method with fork-join doesn't work

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, subscribe, fork-join

This my permission service. I wanna get a boolean array.

```
import { forkJoin, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';                                                   
           

private hasPermission(lessorId: number, userId: number, permission: string): boolean {
 // returns boolean. It works correctly
}

hasPermissionsForX(permissions: string[]): Observable<boolean[]> {
return forkJoin([
  this.userService.getUser(), //returns Observable
  this.lessorService.getLessor() //returns Observable
]).pipe(
  map(([user, lessor]) => permissions.map(permission => this.hasPermission(lessor.lessorId, user.userId, permission)))
)}
```

However, my subscription method is not working. The method had not been getting step into the function. I can't even get console.log response. This is my subscription method.

```
const permissionsToCheck = ['firstPermission', 'secondPermission', 'thirdPermission'];
this.permissionService.hasPermissionsForX(permissionsToCheck).subscribe(([firstPermission, secondPermission, thirdPermission]) => {
  console.log(firstPermission, secondPermission, thirdPermission)                              
})
```

What am I supposed to do? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure, you've subscribed to it ?

Comment: All source Observable for `forkJoin()` have to emit at least once and complete.

Comment: You can add tap operator with your chainable operations to log the results got from your frokJoin observables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the name of your service methods, I'd assume that you actually wanted to use `zip` which emits after all Observables **emit**, instead of `forkJoin` which will only emit once all source observables **complete**.

Also, keep in mind that every observable needs a subscriber in order to emit anything. So, make sure that you actually subscribe to the result of `hasPermissionsForX()`.

[zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip)

[forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked when I used zip instead of forkJoin.